# Singly and doubly linked list (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list

Is LinkedList from java.util doubly linked list?
And do i need to implement my own singly linked list or there is any class for this in java.util?

Just can't find straight answers over web.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: If it is a doubly linked list then it is also a single linked list. The problem would be the opposite.

Comment: Why do you want to know if it's singly/doubly linked? This is an implementation detail that shouldn't be important to you.

Comment: if you are starting with java and LinkedLists i strongly recomends you to implement your own LinkedList, yuo will face some problems, but it worthwhile...

Comment: @m0skit0: I think that remark is unwarranted. `LinkedList` provides many operations that would have *vastly* different performance characteristics depending on whether it's a singly- or doubly-linked list.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Javadoc's LinkedList page contains a straight answer to this question, and is indeed on the web.

Comment: And a doubly linked list implements a singly linked list.

Comment: You can check the source code as well. It's worth to have a look how professionals work.

Comment: @m0skit0: It's perfectly reasonable to care how the list works/performs to inform your decision of which implementation to choose.  For example, you wouldn't want to use a singly-linked list implementation if you're going to be removing the last element a lot, or use a linked list at all if you're going to be doing a lot of random access.

Answer (score 4):

From the [LinkedList API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list.

Unless memory is an issue, a double-linked list is sufficient to meet all the needs that a single-linked list can meet.

Comment: I've seen this in doc, just wasn't 100% sure if it is what i mean't. Thanks.

Comment: It means that the observable behavior is what you would expect for a doubly-linked list -- but the implementation is encapsulated within the class, and can be *anything* that satisfies that specified behavior.